# train a classifer with SVM-light for object detection

Tags: machine-learning, svm, object-detection

I am working with SVM-light. I would like to use SVM-light to train a classifier for object detection. I figured out the syntax to start a training:

```
 svm_learn example2/train_induction.dat example2/model
```

My problem: how can I build the "train_induction.dat" from a
 set of positive and negative pictures?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this question:

- What feature representation should I use for object detection in images with SVMs?
- How do I create an SVM-light data file with (whatever feature representation)?

For an intro to the first question, see [Wikipedia's outline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_object_recognition#Feature-based_methods). [Bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model_in_computer_vision) models based on [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) or sometimes [SURF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeded_Up_Robust_Features) or [HOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) features are fairly standard.

For the second, it depends a lot on what language / libraries you want to use. The features can be extracted from the images using something like [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), [vlfeat](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), or many others. You can then convert those features to the SVM-light format as described on [the SVM-light homepage](http://svmlight.joachims.org/) (no anchors on that page; search for  "The input file").

If you update with what language and library you want to use, we can give more specific advice.

Comment: Thx. I want to use HOG for object detection in OpenCV (for Android).

Comment: I cant find a step by step tutorial thats describes the approach.